# How to develop a dataset for the gravity model of international Trade

Tags: regression, categorical-data, estimation, dataset

The gravity model of International trade is used to estimate the determinants of bilateral trade between countries.

In developing the dataset for the gravity model, do i need to manually pair the countries in terms of total value of exports/imports and the distance or i just need to enter them one by one with their corresponding figures and then STATA will pair them automatically or what?

I want to estimate the likely impacts of China's OBOR on bilateral trade with an African Country. Any advice on the approaches and techniques, I have never used stata nor do i have any skill in regression. Will appreciate.

Comment: Your question might get more attention if you make a few edits.  I'd suggest (1) not writing your title in all caps, (2) briefly explaining what "the gravity model" is, and (3) asking a specific question about statistics.

Comment: It might happen that some time will pass and this question won't get any good answers. In that case, you could flag the post for migration to [economics.SE].

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend reading notes about the gravity model (and about running regressions, in case you aren't familiar with that).

Here's a PDF describing the gravity model of trade:  https://www.nber.org/papers/w16576.pdf.  Here's another one:  http://publications.ut-capitole.fr/15395/1/distance.pdf.

From the second PDF:  the model "describes the patterns of bilateral aggregate trade flows between two countries A and B as proportional to the gross national products of those countries and inversely proportional to the distance between them."

That suggests you'll have to build a dataset with one row of data for each pair of countries A and B.

---

I've attempted to answer this part of your question:  "do I need to manually pair the countries in terms of total value of exports / imports and the distance or I just need to enter them one by one with their corresponding figures and then STATA will pair them automatically or what?"

Getting Stata to run the desired regression is really a programming question.  Hopefully the links I've provided will help you figure out how to assemble your dataset.